# sum only cells that also exist in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
x   y           z
A   1           B
B   2           D
C   3           G
D   4           J
F   5           K
G   6           L
H   7           M
```

I have three columns: x, y & z.

In column "x" are names of elements, in "y" is quantity of those elements, and in "z" are names of elements that have certain characteristic I need.

I need to sum quantity for all elements from column "x" with that characteristic, meaning I need to sum quantity for all elements in column "x" which is also in column "z".

I need formula which will sum, in these case, only 2, 4 and 6, because that is the number of elements which contains certain characteristic, etc number of elements which are also listed in "x" and in "z".

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Y1:Y7)*(COUNTIF(Z1:Z7,X1:X7)>0))
```

your sample data:

[image]

This requires neither a *"helper"* column nor an array formula.

Comment: Excellent: I had been trying the same formula with `=SUM()`, but that seems to use the columns from the current row only, giving an error in the position where you put your formula. I don't understand how `SUMPRODUCT()` knows not to expand the first `COUNTIF()` parameter for each row, so I have a lot of reading to do!

Comment: @AFH I was also a little surprised that *COUNTIF()* worked in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a new column with a formula:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(Z2,X:X,)),0,INDEX(Y:Y,MATCH(Z2,X:X,)))
```

This column can then be totalled as desired.

The `MATCH` method can find the item you're looking for in the other range, the `INDEX` method looks up the equivalent value, and we turn it into 0 if the `MATCH` fails (i.e. the result is `#N/A`)

Comment: Thank you, I have found many solutions by adding a new column, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: @user596129: You should have put that requirement in your question, then! Although I don't think that can be done without using VBA.

Comment: Thank you, I have found many solutions by adding a new column, but I'm trying to avoid that. I looking for something like this: =SUM(SUMIF(x:x,{"B","D","G","J","K","L","M"},y:y))        but I don't want to insert all text I wish to find, because there are to many, so I thought to add another column "z" in which will be all text I need. So, instead of all these criteria I want to add one: to recognize if text from "x" is also in "z"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula for each row, starting in the first data cell (assuming you three columns start in cell A1):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C:C,A2)=0,0,B2)
```

This will return the number of column *y* for all rows that have the value of column *x* appear somewhere in column *z*.

Make sure to adjust the first parameter to `COUNTIF` if you do not want the column headings to interfere.

Afterwards, sum over all values in this new column and you should get the desired result.